# Can we use black list in ESAPI validator methods?

Tags: owasp, esapi

We are trying to implement a xss fix for our jsp web application. we have used the method ESAPI.validator.getValidInput. But this will take whitelist from properties file. My question here is whether blacklist is also available in ESAPI? In our web application many speicial chars are used and some international languages are allowed as input, so finding the whilelist character is complex here. I want to know the approach is correct(using esapi.validator.getvalidate and use whitelist) or not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No, black lists are not supported. Per the Validator interface definition:

"Implementations must adopt a "whitelist" approach to validation where a specific pattern or character set is matched. "Blacklist" approaches that attempt to identify the invalid or disallowed characters are much more likely to allow a bypass with encoding or other tricks."

https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html